# Why I don't get horizontally-polarized TVs in the satellite from time to time?

Tags: polarity

Something like once every 2 days I cannot watch **horizontal** SAT channels for about a half day. It says "no signal". During this "no signal" time I get very rarely watchable time. Like 1 minute in an hour. The after this "no signal" time ends there is no issue for about 1-2 days. That was for H.

On the other hand, I never have issues with **vertically**-polarized TV channels.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The 14/18V electrically controlled polarizer is integrated within the LNC and runs thru the coax cable.

Issues may exist with DC supply voltage, polarotor, the co-rotor, the skew alignment, the channel programming or the LNC or very advanced microwave propagation issues with solar angle.

[C-band Channel Polarity map.](http://www.satcruiser.com/c-band_chart.htm)

[Map for others](https://www.lyngsat.com/)